# disable video rendering in presenter view

Tags: video, powerpoint, presenter

The first time I'm working with video sequences within Powerpoint.

I am a bit annoyed regarding the simultaneous video rendering in both the presenter view and the main view, because the rendering may exhibit little jitter resp. time lag.
Curiously, upon the beginning of the work, the presenter view's video WAS static, kept on the first frame. That was okay.

I do not find any option regarding this; as such I can't explain why the behaviour has changed. I'd be grateful for any useful hints.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the default behavior of PowerPoint. Something went awry with your installation. Please try an Office repair. In Win10: Start button>Settings>Apps. Select Microsoft Office, then click on Modify. Online Repair, then click on Repair. Restart, retest.